# how to remove left and top border from a text box?

Tags: text, textbox, border

I'm trying to put text inside a box in the shape of a corner, with no top or left border, as shown in the image below
[image].

I've tried many CSS tricks by changing the color of each border, so I chose transparent for the left and top borders, but here's the issue i want to add :after for the same box so i cannot add it since i have a transparent borders so the extra border thingy will not look like the image .

```
 border-color: transparent #0ff #f0f transparent;
```

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered there is a proprety called "border-style" this proprety solved my problem please check out the code :

```
.box {
background-color: lightgrey;
width: 300px;
border: 7px solid green;
padding: 50px;
margin: 20px;
border-right-style: none;
border-top-style: none;
```

}